# Can not find my Term Store ,, all the Term store were removed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, managed-metadata, service-application

I have created a new Term store tree, and inside my Category column for my Wiki Pages , i link the Column to my metadata navigation. but now when i want to assign a new value for my Category column and select a new term , i was not able to access the term store and the Category colum was disabled as follow:-
[image]

when i access the Metadata navigation service, i could not find the old term store any more also?
[image]

Can any one advice what might be causing this stange behavioure ?
Thanks

Comment: Since your term store management tool does not even see your termstore, I think you need to check if the Managed Metadata Service (in CA) is running, check if your managed metadata service is configured properly, see if you can access it through code (http://richardihogan.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-retreive-meanaged-meta-data-service-and-terms-store-ids/), make sure to check both TermStore collections on the TaxonomySession object, one is for "active" or something, other is a complete list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link between your field and the termstore is probably not correctly set.

In order to display the correct values, a termstore field (TaxonomyField) contains the id's of your termstore and termset you want to display. However this ID is different on every server. You need to make sure when using a TaxonomyField the field is configured with the correct id's on that server.

Here is some c# on how to do it. You can find the id's on the bottom of the property page of your termstore manager in SharePoint.

```
private void LinkMmdField(TaxonomyField field, LinkMmd linkinfo, TaxonomySession session)
{     
    TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[linkinfo.TermStoreName];
    Group group = termStore.Groups[linkinfo.TermGroupName];
    TermSet  termset = group.TermSets[linkinfo.TermSetName];

    if (termset != null)
    {
        field.SspId = termStore.Id;
        field.TermSetId = termset.Id;
        field.Update();
    }
}
```